# Looping in directory names (string error)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to python, so I apologise in advance for not having the most optimal code :)

Anyways, I'm trying to do some plots with the matplotlib package, and is currently at this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

PATH_TO_YDATA1 = '401\PTV-06'
PATH_TO_YDATA2 = '401\PTV-11'
PATH_TO_YDATA3 = '401\PTV-16'
PATH_TO_YDATA4 = '401\PTV-21'
PATH_TO_YDATA5 = '401\PTV-26'
PATH_TO_YDATA6 = '401\PTV-31'
PATH_TO_YDATA7 = '401\PTV-36'
PATH_TO_YDATA8 = '401\PTV-REF'

x = np.loadtxt('401\dosex.txt')*1.1

path = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for pathnumber in path:
    pathname = "%s%d" %("PATH_TO_YDATA", pathnumber)
    print pathname
    for f in sorted(os.listdir(pathname), key=lambda f: int(f.split('-')[-2])):
        y = np.loadtxt(pathname + '/' + f)
        if int(f.split('-')[-2]) < 90:
            plt.plot(x, y*100, color='#70ad47', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.0, label=f.split('-')[-2] + '/' + str(360 - int(f.split('-')[-2])))
        elif int(f.split('-')[-2]) == 90:
            plt.plot(x, y * 100, color='#5b9bd5', linestyle='solid', linewidth=2.0, label=f.split('-')[-2] + '/' + str(360 - int(f.split('-')[-2])))
        elif int(f.split('-')[-2]) > 90:
            plt.plot(x, y * 100, color='#ed7d31', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.0, label=f.split('-')[-2] + '/' + str(360 - int(f.split('-')[-2])))
        plt.subplot(2, 4, 1)
        plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 100])
        plt.grid(True)
    plt.title(re.split('[- .]', f)[-2])

plt.plot((77, 77), (0, 100), 'k-')
plt.show()
```

I know that it will also be possible to loop through the `PATH_TO_YDATA# = ...` instead of having 8 lines. But I'm just taking one step at a time :)

Nopw, my problem is that at the "print pathname" line, I actually get an output of `PATH_TO_YDATA1` for the first loop, and then it just stops with the error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'PATH_TO_YDATA1/*.*'
```

And I know that the code works if I just type in `PATH_TO_YDATA1` instead of pathname both places. So my guess is, that it has something to do with paths to folders may not be a string or something. However, I don't seem to be able to figure out how to make it into "not a string", so that the code will read it is a path directory, and not just some random text.

So basically, the code works if I type in the `PATH_TO_YDATA#` manually instead of using the loop pathnames, so the flaw is at the pathname loop.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your loop, `pathname` is not referring to the variables that you defined earlier, it is simply a string. To get the value of a variable (the actual path) from a string containing the variable name, you can use `eval(pathname)`. For example:

```
PATH_TO_YDATA1 = '401\PTV-06'
PATH_TO_YDATA2 = '401\PTV-11'
PATH_TO_YDATA3 = '401\PTV-16'

path = [1,2,3] 

for pathnumber in path:
    path = "%s%d"%("PATH_TO_YDATA",pathnumber)
    print(path, eval(path))
```

Prints:

> PATH_TO_YDATA1 401\PTV-06
>
> PATH_TO_YDATA2 401\PTV-11
>
> PATH_TO_YDATA3 401\PTV-16

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend a different approach. In passing: if you ever need to resort to `eval` it is probable (but not certain) that you are doing something the wrong way.

In this case use a list, not lots of individual variables:

```
PATHS_TO_YDATA = [ 
    '401\PTV-06', 
    '401\PTV-11', 
    ... 
    '401\PTV-REF',
]

for i,name in enumerate( PATHS_TO_YDATA):
     print( "Path to YDATA number {} is {}" .format( i+1, name ) )
```

You may not actually need the index `i`. If you just want to process in order the files whose names are contained in the list `PATHS_TO_YDATA`, just use

```
for name in PATHS_TO_YDATA:
    # process name
```